# How to increase /boot partition size

Tags: updates, disk

I'm trying to update my PC from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04, and I used a tutorial to install Ubuntu which was probably outdated and told me to assign less memory than what I need for 20.10 or 21.04. Does anyone know how to increase the size of a partition, or should I delete the partition and create a new one, or should I reinstall it altogether?

Comment: There is no supported "update" path directly from 20.04 to 21.04. The two supported paths are 1) Reinstall and 2) Release upgrade to 20.10, then again to 21.04. Since you need to re-partition anyway, good time for a reinstall.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys! Luckily I haven't got much data on this because i've only had this PC a few weeks, so I'll just back it up onto a USB.

Comment: In a short while there will be an option appear on the computer screen to update from 20.04 to 21.04 just like there is to go from 18.04 to 20.04.  t just has not been done yet.